# Как сделать активный слайд центрированным, если "centeredSlides: true" не работает?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scss, swiper

Помогите, пожалуйста. Мне нужно сделать слайдер следующего вида
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но мой слайдер по какой-то причине не центрирован. Мне нужно три слайда, где активный слайд больше и центрирован...

Вот что я пытался сделать [codepen](https://codepen.io/Mukzer/pen/JjNLaXO?editors=0110) [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mukzer/gq6pk3a4/1/)

```js
const swiper = new Swiper(".slider-container", {
    slideClass: 'slider-item',
    wrapperClass: 'slider-items',
    slideActiveClass: 'slider-item--active',
    spaceBetween: 57,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    centeredSlides: true,
    loop: true,
    pagination: {
        el: '.slider-pagination',
        clickable: true,
    },
    speed: 1000,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.slider-button-next',
        prevEl: '.slider-button-prev',
    },
});
```

```css
.slider-container {
     width: 1230px;
     height: 425px;
}
 .slider-items {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     height: 100%;
     padding-bottom: 50px;
}
 .slider-item {
     cursor: pointer;
     opacity: 0.6;
     transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
     width: 285px;
     height: 190px;
}
 .slider-item img {
     width: 285px;
     height: 190px;
     transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
 .slider .slider-item--active {
     opacity: 1;
     transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
     width: 545px;
     height: 365px;
}
 .slider .slider-item--active img {
     width: 545px;
     height: 365px;
     transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
 .slider .slider-navigation {
     right: 0;
     left: 0;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
 .swiper-button-disabled {
     opacity: 0.3;
}
 .swiper-pagination-bullet {
     width: 10px;
     height: 10px;
     background: none;
     border: 1px solid #dfd7d3;
     opacity: 1;
     transition: all 0.3s;
}
 .swiper-pagination-bullet + .swiper-pagination-bullet {
     margin-left: 10px;
}
 .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
     background: #ca6d38;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(243, 241, 239, 0.25);
}
 .slider-navigation {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     width: 100%;
     max-width: 556px;
}
 .slider-button {
     display: inline;
     cursor: pointer;
     transition: all 0.3s;
}
 .slider-button svg {
     width: 91px;
     height: 11px;
     fill: #ca6d38;
}
 .slider-button:hover path {
     box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(243, 241, 239, 0.25);
}
 .slider-button:active path {
     box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(243, 241, 239, 0.25);
     fill: rgba(202, 109, 56, 0.8);
}
 .slider-button-prev svg {
     transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
<section class="slider section-outer">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="slider-inner">
                            <div class="slider-container swiper-container">
                                <div class="slider-items">
                                    <div class="slider-item">
                                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/vdCRM7c/slider-photo-1.jpg">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slider-item">
                                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/XLz2LLs/slider-photo-2.jpg">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slider-item">
                                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/dG3gyCV/slider-photo-3.jpg">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slider-item">
                                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/vdCRM7c/slider-photo-1.jpg">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slider-item">
                                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/XLz2LLs/slider-photo-2.jpg">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slider-item">
                                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/dG3gyCV/slider-photo-3.jpg">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="slider-navigation reviews-navigation">
                                    <div class="slider-button slider-button-prev">
                                        <svg viewBox="0 0 66 10">
                                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M61.2071 0.292847L65.9142 4.99995L61.2071 9.70706L59.7929 8.29285L62.0858 5.99995H0V3.99995H62.0858L59.7929 1.70706L61.2071 0.292847Z"/>
                                        </svg>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slider-pagination"></div>
                                    <div class="slider-button slider-button-next">
                                        <svg viewBox="0 0 66 10">
                                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M61.2071 0.292847L65.9142 4.99995L61.2071 9.70706L59.7929 8.29285L62.0858 5.99995H0V3.99995H62.0858L59.7929 1.70706L61.2071 0.292847Z"/>
                                        </svg>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Надеюсь на помощь, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно было в скрипте поставить `spaceBetween: 0`
Если помог с решением, пожалуйста поставьте галочку.

```js
const swiper = new Swiper(".slider-container", {
    slideClass: 'slider-item',
    wrapperClass: 'slider-items',
    slideActiveClass: 'slider-item--active',
    spaceBetween: 0,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    centeredSlides: true,
    loop: true,
    pagination: {
        el: '.slider-pagination',
        clickable: true,
    },
    speed: 1000,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.slider-button-next',
        prevEl: '.slider-button-prev',
    },
});
```

```css
.slider-container {
     width: 1230px;
     height: 425px;
}
 .slider-items {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     height: 100%;
     padding-bottom: 50px;
}
 .slider-item {
     cursor: pointer;
     opacity: 0.6;
     transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
     width: 285px;
     height: 190px;
}
 .slider-item img {
     width: 285px;
     height: 190px;
     transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
 .slider .slider-item--active {
     opacity: 1;
     transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
     width: 545px;
     height: 365px;
}
 .slider .slider-item--active img {
     width: 545px;
     height: 365px;
     transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
 .slider .slider-navigation {
     right: 0;
     left: 0;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
 .swiper-button-disabled {
     opacity: 0.3;
}
 .swiper-pagination-bullet {
     width: 10px;
     height: 10px;
     background: none;
     border: 1px solid #dfd7d3;
     opacity: 1;
     transition: all 0.3s;
}
 .swiper-pagination-bullet + .swiper-pagination-bullet {
     margin-left: 10px;
}
 .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
     background: #ca6d38;
     box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(243, 241, 239, 0.25);
}
 .slider-navigation {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     width: 100%;
     max-width: 556px;
}
 .slider-button {
     display: inline;
     cursor: pointer;
     transition: all 0.3s;
}
 .slider-button svg {
     width: 91px;
     height: 11px;
     fill: #ca6d38;
}
 .slider-button:hover path {
     box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(243, 241, 239, 0.25);
}
 .slider-button:active path {
     box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(243, 241, 239, 0.25);
     fill: rgba(202, 109, 56, 0.8);
}
 .slider-button-prev svg {
     transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
<section class="slider section-outer">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="slider-inner">
                            <div class="slider-container swiper-container">
                                <div class="slider-items">
                                    <div class="slider-item">
                                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/vdCRM7c/slider-photo-1.jpg">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slider-item">
                                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/XLz2LLs/slider-photo-2.jpg">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slider-item">
                                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/dG3gyCV/slider-photo-3.jpg">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slider-item">
                                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/vdCRM7c/slider-photo-1.jpg">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slider-item">
                                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/XLz2LLs/slider-photo-2.jpg">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slider-item">
                                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/dG3gyCV/slider-photo-3.jpg">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="slider-navigation reviews-navigation">
                                    <div class="slider-button slider-button-prev">
                                        <svg viewBox="0 0 66 10">
                                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M61.2071 0.292847L65.9142 4.99995L61.2071 9.70706L59.7929 8.29285L62.0858 5.99995H0V3.99995H62.0858L59.7929 1.70706L61.2071 0.292847Z"/>
                                        </svg>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slider-pagination"></div>
                                    <div class="slider-button slider-button-next">
                                        <svg viewBox="0 0 66 10">
                                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M61.2071 0.292847L65.9142 4.99995L61.2071 9.70706L59.7929 8.29285L62.0858 5.99995H0V3.99995H62.0858L59.7929 1.70706L61.2071 0.292847Z"/>
                                        </svg>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Даже если я буду задавать отступы между слайдами при помощи margin, всё равно почему он сдвигается в левую сторону и не центрируется.

Comment: @Mukzer сейчас все центрируется

Comment: Интересно это работает, оно центрируется только когда меняется ширина окна, если сейчас открыть твой пример слайдер по центру, но если нажать на стрелку или свайпнуть то он уже не по центру...

Comment: @Mukzer только проверял и сдвигал и стрелку нажимал всегда по центру, проверяйте здесь на форуме

Comment: https://ibb.co/PQbB3Tz
https://ibb.co/d412Qz1
Может только у меня так...

Comment: @Mukzer сейчас посмотрел, да действительно сдвигается, ближе к вечеру посмотрю внимательнее

Comment: Получилось что-то сделать с этим слайдером?

Comment: @Mukzer Нет, к сожалению